# How much security is really needed on a "private" website?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I'm asking this as I maintain a small website for a fairly isolated group of people (no more than 80). It currently has a simple log in function (e-mail, password) and the data that is "protected" is merely contact information to our members (telephone, address, e-mail). The website is written in PHP and use My SQL.

These last couple of days, I've been reading through the forums and other sites about web site security, since I would like to enhance it on our site. Right now the security consists of SQL-injection protection and MD5-hashed passwords stored in a database. This feels abit inadequate but I also feel that it's easy to take it TOO far. I mean it's not exactly nuclear launch codes here, but data people usually feel abit unconfortable to display online. The site itself is hosted by a fairly renown web host.

The only threat I can see right now are pranksters stumbling across the site and trying some of their home made concotion?

So I thought somewhere in the middle would suffice. Like

- SQL-injection protection (enhance if needed)
- Stronger hash method with salt
- XSS-protection
- DDoS-protection
- SSL when accessing the member area

What do you more experienced people out ther think?

Update: I would like to add that I do everything myself and there is no budget for buying fancy crypto techniques or hiring professional programmers.

Comment: _The site itself is hosted by a fairly renown web host_... not private anymore!

Comment: Use bcrypt to hash your passwords, it is not for high security sites only, and using it can be as easy, as using an md5 hash. There are libraries like [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/), and if you want to understand how it works, you can read this [article](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt).

Comment: Your critical ones will be SQL Injection protection, Minimum password complexity for user accounts, A strong password on your SSH/admin account (or disable password auth entirely and use public-key authentication for the admin account), remote file inclusion protection, XSS protection, and user-isolation for your httpd process.  Nice to have would be SSL for post-auth content.  Not required in this case are improved password hashing in the database, DDoS protection, and CSRF protection.  There's nothing wrong with having those, but unless you get a targeted attacker, you won't need them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enhance security for **SQL injection**, you must see:

- [Best Way to Prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

It would tell you to use `PDO`, parameterized queries.

To learn about **general security issues**, see this post which covers a lot:

- [PHP Security Guide (By PHP Security Consotium)](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/)

**Audit** your site in terms of security using:

- [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

And

- [PHPSec](http://phpsec.xqus.com/)

> phpSec is a open-source PHP security library that takes care of the
>   common security tasks a web developer faces.

Comment: Would that require installation? Cause I don't have access to the server since it's a shared host.

Comment: @Sandokan: Yes it would but don't worry about it. Read the security guide and then code considering those points.

Answer (score 1):

Add CSRF vulnerability protection to your security list

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add [Remote file inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_file_inclusion).