# unescaping double quotes in php

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

My PHP code is:

```
$query="select company_name from company_names where cik=".$cik;
```

Which on printing gives

```
select company_name from company_names where cik=0001001871
```

I would like to get the output like

```
select company_name from company_names where cik='0001001871'
```

How do I add the single quotes in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: But why you want single quotes on integer

Comment: and if cik is string type then you are doing a foolish thing of storing int as string

Comment: thing is that Ive stored integer values in array var testArray=['0001002811','0001001807','0001003344'];... Im trying to access these values with $cik...

Comment: I knw im in trouble.. big time..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
$query = "select company_name from company_names where cik = '$cik'";
```

Or:

```
$query = "select company_name from company_names where cik = '" . $cik . "'";
```

Notice that to prevent **SQL Injection**, see this:

- [Best Way to Prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077685/how-much-security-is-really-needed-on-a-private-website/11077748#11077748)

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: what if $cik contains McDonald's ?

Comment: @thebjorn: You need to ask that question on your own, this answers OP's question, `cik=0001001871`. It contains number.

Comment: thanks for the answer... do yu know the postgres equivalent of mysql_fetch_assoc()?

Comment: @user1371896: It is `pg_fetch_assoc()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="select company_name from company_names where cik='".$cik."'";
```